# $_POST зависит от чекбокса

Tags: php, post

Доброго времени суток, из `select` выбирается значение, `switch` определяет какое действие выполнять. В форме вместе с `select` есть чекбокс. Так вот, если чекбокс не выбран, то ничего не происходит, значение отправляется верное, но `switch` его инорирует. Если чекбокс активирован, `switch` работает. Вот форма:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="dropdownlist" id="select-interval">
        <select class="select rounded shadow" id="interval" name="interval" size="1">
            <option disabled selected>Выберите интервал</option>
            <option value="week">Неделя</option>
            <option value="month">Месяц</option>
            <option value="date-selector" data-type="range">Выберите даты...</option>
        </select>
        <table id="hidden-table" class="hidden"><tr>
        <td>Дата начала</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="start_date"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Дата конца</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="end_date"/></td></tr></table>
        <input class="submit color_button rounded" type="submit" value="Выбрать" name="show-select" id="submit" /><Br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="otchet" value="a1">Создать отчет
</form>
```

Switch:

```
switch($_POST['interval'])
{
case "week": //Неделя
    $TemplatePath = 'docs/TemplateWeek.docx';
    $table_title = 'Активность за неделю';
    $strSQL="SELECT * FROM worktime WHERE pcid='".$_SESSION['currpcid']."' AND year(date)= year(now()) AND week(date, 1) = week(now(), 1) ORDER BY date"; //Выбор записей за неделю 
break;
case "month": //Месяц
    $TemplatePath = 'docs/TemplateMonth.docx';
    $table_title = 'Активность за прошедший месяц';
    $strSQL="SELECT * FROM worktime WHERE pcid='".$_SESSION['currpcid']."' AND date > LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) AND date < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY date"; //Выбор записей за неделю
break;
case "date-selector": //Выбор даты
    $start_date=$_REQUEST['start_date'];
    date_create($start_date)->Format('Y-m-d');
    if (!$_REQUEST['end_date'])
    {
        $end_date=date("Y-m-d");
    }
    else
        $end_date=$_REQUEST['end_date'];
    if ($start_date > $end_date)
    {
        echo "Начальная дата должна быть меньше даты окончания!";
    }   
    date_create($end_date)->Format('Y-m-d');
    $TemplatePath = 'docs/TemplateInterval.docx';
    $table_title = 'Активность с' . $start_date . ' по ' . $end_date . '';  
    $strSQL="SELECT * FROM worktime WHERE pcid='".$_SESSION['currpcid']."' AND date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ORDER BY date DESC"; //Выбор записей по интервалу
break;
}
```

Действие при нажатом чекбоксе:

```
if ($_POST['otchet'])
{
    $OtchetDateTime = date('y-d-m H-i-s');
    require_once 'PHPWord.php';
    $PHPWord = new PHPWord();
    $document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate($TemplatePath);
    $document->setValue('Value1', '00001');
    $document->setValue('Value2', $resultpcname[0]);
    $document->setValue('Value3', $globaltime);
    $document->setValue('Value4', $totaltimeout);
    $document->setValue('Value5', date('Y'));
    $document->setValue('Value6', date("m.d.y"));
    $document->setValue('Value7', $OtchetDateTime);
    $document->setValue('Value8', $start_date);
    $document->setValue('Value9', $end_date);
    $document->save('docs/reports/'. $OtchetDateTime .' '. $_POST['interval']. '-report.docx');
}
```

Comment: Перед `switch` поставьте `var_dump($_POST);` и смотрите на его содержимое.

Comment: `array (size=4)
  'interval' => string 'week' (length=4)
  'start_date' => string '' (length=0)
  'end_date' => string '' (length=0)
  'show-select' => string 'Выбрать' (length=14)`

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от браузера, значение чекбокса будет разный (значение по умолчанию). Как правило это 1,on. Если чекбокс не проставлен, то он не отправляется на сервер. Возможно проблема в том, что у вас возникает предупреждение/ошибка. Попробуйте проверять его существование

```
if(array_key_exists('otchet', $_POST) && $_POST['otchet']){...}
```

PS. Не очень понятно как switch связан с этим условием. Было бы не плохо, если бы был представлен полный код, отражающий их зависимость друг от друга.

Comment: Значения switch и checkbox находятся в одной форме.Вставил ваш код - безрезультатно. Switch выполняется только с нажатым чекбоксом

Comment: Т.е. без чекбокса должна выводиться таблица с записями (на основе запроса из switch), а с чекбоксом тоже самое + формирование отчета.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему перемещением блока `if ($_POST['otchet'])` с шапки в тело документа.